# Prevent input validation on an input prarameter of a method

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns

Currently:

```
void deleteCase(caseId, version){
  var case = getCase(caseId);
  if(case is null) throw ArgumentNullException(caseId);
  
  if(verifyVersion(case, version) == false) return;
  
  return delete(case);
}
bool verifyVersion(case, version){
  if(version is null) throw ArgumentNullException(version);
  
  // call db to verify the version is mathching

}
```

`deleteCase(1, null)` => it throws an exception as version cannot be `null`

Question: now we have a situation we can delete a case without providing its version, it means being able to call `deleteCase`  without providing `version`.

Solution 1: add an optional flag indicating no need to check version

```
void deleteCase(caseId, version, checkVersion = true){
  var case = getCase(caseId);
  if(case is null) throw ArgumentNullException(caseId);
  
  if(checkVersion == true AND verifyVersion(case, version) == false) return;
  
  return delete(case);
}
```

old calls:
`deleteCase(1, null)` => works as expected before since checkVersion is by default true
`deleteCase(1, "1.0")` => works as expected before since checkVersion is by default true
new calls:
`deleteCase(1, null, true)` => works as expected before
`deleteCase(1, null, false)` => works as we want
`deleteCase(1)` => works as we want

The problem with that is we've added a new parameter to control another parameter => not accepted.
And also we should not be able to do `deleteCase(1, "1.0", false)` which version is redundant

Solution 2: overload deleteCase to not having version parameter

```
void deleteCase(caseId){
  var case = getCase(caseId);
  if(case is null) throw ArgumentNullException(caseId);
  
  return delete(case);
}
void deleteCase(caseId, version){
  var case = getCase(caseId);
  if(case is null) throw ArgumentNullException(caseId);
  
  if(verifyVersion(case, version) == false) return;
  
  return deleteCase(caseId);
}
```

Now any `deleteCase` calls work as expected. But the only problem is `getCase` gets called twice if version is passed which makes it anti performant.

Any idea what can we do to make one call?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't go with the second option and return `delete(case)` for both? If your complaint is that the `getCase` null checks are duplicated in both, you can have both versions accept `case` only instead of `caseId`.

Comment: @wLui155 can you formulate yr comment as answer

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be creating a private method which accepts the case object and deletes it. Both public deleteCase methods will call the private method. You will apply DRY practice.

But I want to warn you about passing control flags as in your first solution. It's really a bad idea because the decision-making concern moves to the client and it will leak the logic to the client code.

On the other hand, you should make these two methods special so that it would be obvious for developers to know why they would use one or another. I mean use another name for the method to indicate in what circumstances you use the method, something like *deleteCaseForSpecificVersion*.
Or maybe it would be better if you introduce a factory to choose a strategy for deletion.